# animation of bootstrap nav menu in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

```js
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
         $('#about_menu').hover(function(){
   $('#about_sub_menu').toggle('slow')
   
  });
  $('#admission_menu').hover(function(){
   $('#admission_sub_menu').toggle('slow')
   
  });
  $('#student_menu').hover(function(){
   $('#student_sub_menu').toggle('slow')
   
  }); 
    });
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse ">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown" ><a id="about_menu" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">About Us <span
                             class="caret">
                            </span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="about_sub_menu">
                            <li><a href="introduction.php">Introduction</a></li>
                            <li><a href="location.php"> Location</a></li>
                            <li><a href="board-of-governors.php"> Board Of Governors</a></li>
                            <li><a href="vp-message.php"> VP Message</a></li>
                            </ul>                
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown"><a id="admission_menu" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Admissions<span 
                            class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="admission_sub_menu" >
                            <li><a href="criteria.php">Criteria</a></li>
                            <li><a href="fee-structure.php">Fee Structure</a></li>
                            <li><a href="paper-pattern.php">Paper Pattern</a></li>
                            <li><a href="student-reg-form.php">Student Registration Form</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown"><a id="student_menu" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Students <span 
                            class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="student_sub_menu">
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Academics</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="menu-item"><a href="syllabus.php">Syllabus</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            </li>
</ul>
```

hello all!!

i am just beginner in bootstrap and jquery.

i want to animate the navigation menu which i built in bootstrap. but when i hover on Li then it shows me the submenus.

but the problem is that when i want to hover on submenu then it disappears. i want that when i hover on submenu then it shouldn't disappear and when i leave the mouse cursor from Li or submenu and hover on another li then the previous submenu should disappear.

i would really appreciate your help and thanks in advance.

regards
naveed ali

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind `hover` event to `li.dropdown` elements. Sub-menu's are not under `a` elements and if you hover a sub-menu, you trigger `mouseout` event of `a` element. If you use `li.dropdown` when you hover li and sub-menu appears it also widens the area of `li` (because sub-menu is inside that `li`) and you mouse pointer won't get outside of `li`.

BTW you can use `.dropdown` directly to bind `hover` event. No need for binding them with their id's.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.dropdown').hover(function() {
      $('ul', this).stop(true, true).toggle('slow');
    });
  });
```

```css
ul.nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.nav > li > ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse ">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a id="about_menu" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">About Us <span
                             class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="about_sub_menu">
        <li><a href="introduction.php">Introduction</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="location.php"> Location</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="board-of-governors.php"> Board Of Governors</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="vp-message.php"> VP Message</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a id="admission_menu" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Admissions<span 
                            class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="admission_sub_menu">
        <li><a href="criteria.php">Criteria</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="fee-structure.php">Fee Structure</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="paper-pattern.php">Paper Pattern</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="student-reg-form.php">Student Registration Form</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a id="student_menu" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Students <span 
                            class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="student_sub_menu">
        <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Academics</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="syllabus.php">Syllabus</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: @EmmreErkan if i want to hover submenu and that menu have additional submenus then what should we do now??

Comment: when i hover on "students" li above then the submenu of "academics" are also shown but i want that when i hover on a submenu "academics" then the submenu of "academics" which is "syllabus" shown that time.

Comment: Use this: `$('> ul', this)`